# Can I insert a directive inside another directive - reStructuredText/Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to insert an image inside my admonition directive:

```
.. admonition:: John

   Social Network
     .. image: './_static/images/social/facebook.png'
        :target: `facebook`_
```

But this doesn't work. There is no picture shown inside the page. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your image directive. First, you need an additional colon (`:`) following `.. image`. Second, you do not need the quotation marks (`'`) around the image file path. Provided there's a valid `facebook` reference elsewhere in the document, the following code works for me:

```
.. admonition:: John

   Social Network
     .. image:: /path/to/facebook.png
        :target: `facebook`_
```

Without the second colon, the image is just a comment (and likely appears as such in HTML output, for example). See the [image directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) documentation for details.